# How to insert multi select dropdown option into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<select name="sel[]" class="selectpicker" multiple title="selections">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

My problem is that data is not inserted into MySQL, received insert MySQL array error instead.

My database insert code

```
 <?php
$selx=implode(",",$_POST['sel']);

?>
<?PHP
require_once('connection.php');


$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO anket_iki (selx)
VALUES ('$selx')");
while(mysql_fetch_array($query));
if($query) {
echo "Anketiniz Kaydedilmiştir ! Katkınız için teşekkür ederiz...";
echo "<br /><br />Ana Sayafaya Yönlendiriliyorusunuz ...";
} else {
}
}
?>
```

How to insert my data into MySQL database?

i find it :)

$selx=implode(",",$_POST['sel']);

this work it , early posted data mysql database

Comment: What? - Could you please edit your question to make it more clear?

Comment: Could you show us also how you try to insert that data into your database? Check this also - [ask]

Comment: LOL what are you asking man ?

Comment: 1. in which way you are trying to insert in column? 2. comma separated,serialized or single-single row for each one? 3. what is the collation of the column? 4.And most important you have to show your complete code of insertion along with this form code?

Comment: Ok, you need to read this and start again, you are getting things backwards and using outdated techniques, have a read - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
<select name="sel[]" class="selectpicker" multiple title="selections">
```

here

> sel[]

is an array that can be used to get all the selected value. 
You can use foreach loop to get its selected value and then insert it in database.

**Note: You cannot insert $sel to a table column in database as it is an arrray**

Comment: ok but database record array , i want read selection data 1,2,3 multiple selection , how to make this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not stating what method you are using to insert into the database, mysqli or PDO, but using one of these options would allow you to insert the data into the database.

```
    <?php

    $data = serialize( $_POST );
    //insert $data into database

    $data = implode( ',', $_POST );
    //insert $data into database

    foreach( $_POST[ 'sel' ] as $p )
    {
        $data = $p;
        //insert $data into database
    }

    ?>
```

The `$data` variable in each case will allow for insertion into a database without issue.  These are not the only three ways to prepare the data for insertion but will get you going.  If you need help with the database query then post what you have and we can take a look.

Comment: my option value not dynamic my option value static

Comment: It does not matter if the select is static or dynamic, as Mayank stated the `sel[]` will be sent as an array when you submit the form, therefor you have to deal with the array before you can insert the data into the database, hence the code above.  This will deal with the data array so you can insert it into the database.

Comment: i can't insert database selection options , i want selection options 1,2,3,4 or all options insert mysql database

Comment: i can only last selection added mysql table  i can't  all selection  added mysql table

Comment: Show the code you are using to insert into the database, place it into the original post.

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach($mydata as $key => $data)
<select name="sel[]" class="selectpicker" multiple_title="selections">
<option value="$key">$data</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: to save data into mysql table.

Comment: But it doesn't, this would loop through the `$mydata` array and create a dropdown for each element in the array.  This would not do anything for a mysql database.  Also formatting is the key to producing answers, gives a better understanding of how to implement the code.

Comment: my bad, you are right after creating dropdown you need to write mysql query to store data into database.

Comment: my option value not dynamic my option value static , but not insert mysql data base selection multiple option

Comment: have you tried replacing "multiple title" to "multiple" if this doesn't work then you may have written mysql code wrong. And i dont know why you are taking name as array sel[] return garbage value.

Comment: check this example hope it will work. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp